# iPhone crash during layer animation after being in background

Tags: ios, crash, calayer, nstimer

I'm having trouble fixing a pesky crash. I can't figure out how to accurately reproduce it,
but it only occurs after the app comes out of the background. I get this crash every 2+ days.

In applicationDidBecomeActive:, I restart a timer that fires every 0.4 seconds. It calls:

```
- (void)rotate {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-[LocationModel    instance].heading.magneticHeading));
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Also in RotateView, is the drawRect, whose body is at line 41 as seen in the crash report.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [img drawInRect:rect]; // line 41
}
```

img is a small UIImage loaded with imageNamed: and stored in an ivar.

Any advice? I have little experience with crash reports.

Thanks!

---

Crash report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x3001b482
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x333a6c98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   MyApp                           0x000259bc -[RotateView drawRect:] (RotateView.m:41)
2   UIKit                             0x34f4a9fe -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 258
3   QuartzCore                        0x3058efa6 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 86
4   QuartzCore                        0x3058ed24 _ZL16backing_callbackP9CGContextPv + 32
5   QuartzCore                        0x3058e776 CABackingStoreUpdate + 1226
6   QuartzCore                        0x3058e178 -[CALayer _display] + 724
7   QuartzCore                        0x3058de86 -[CALayer display] + 134
8   QuartzCore                        0x30582706 CALayerDisplayIfNeeded + 178
9   QuartzCore                        0x305821c6 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 214
10  QuartzCore                        0x30581fd0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 184
11  QuartzCore                        0x30580900 CA::Transaction::pop() + 120
12  QuartzCore                        0x3058087e +[CATransaction commit] + 22
13  UIKit                             0x35096bcc _UIWindowUpdateVisibleContextOrder + 136
14  UIKit                             0x35096c60 +[UIWindow _prepareWindowsForAppResume] + 4
15  UIKit                             0x3508f3de -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] + 66
16  UIKit                             0x34f39e20 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2724
17  UIKit                             0x34f3920e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
18  UIKit                             0x34f38c4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
19  GraphicsServices                  0x35873e70 PurpleEventCallback + 660
20  GraphicsServices                  0x35873efa PurpleEventSignalCallback + 10
21  CoreFoundation                    0x36126a72 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
22  CoreFoundation                    0x36128758 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
23  CoreFoundation                    0x361294e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
24  CoreFoundation                    0x360b9ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
25  CoreFoundation                    0x360b9dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
26  GraphicsServices                  0x35873418 GSEventRunModal + 108
27  GraphicsServices                  0x358734c4 GSEventRun + 56
28  UIKit                             0x34f63d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
29  UIKit                             0x34f61800 UIApplicationMain + 664
30  MyApp                           0x000026c4 main (main.m:14)
31  MyApp                           0x0000266c start + 32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS generally means you released an object then called that object later.  Try enabling NSZombies to find it.  There are numerous tutorials on how to do it.  Here's one  to start http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/

Comment: It's enabled already. Would NSZombies show something in the crash log?

Comment: With zombies enabled, I usually get something like 'message sent to deallocated instance 0x80d7c00' and go from there.  You could also try instruments, they have a way to find zombies as well.

Comment: I understand these tools, but as I mention above, the crash happens infrequently. I can't debug through the device.

Comment: "Can't debug through the device" meaning I can't leave the device attached for two days.